# Passing a func condition in java

Tags: java, function, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone know how or have an example of a method that takes in a function that'll take in a boolean value and return a boolean value? And how to use it in code? Basically I want to pass a condition to a method and have it be evaluated in the method resolving to true or false. I want to pass a condition and check it for a boolean value before exiting the method. Please help. I have this defined:

```
public void clickAndWaitForCondition(By locator, Function<Boolean,Boolean> condition){
   Webdriver.findElement(locator).click ();
   for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
   {
      if (condition.apply() == true)
      { 
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your question is purely how to call that method, you can either call it using an instance of `Function` like this:

```
ClickAndWaitForCondition(by, new Function<Boolean,Boolean> {
  @Override
  public Boolean apply(Boolean aBoolean) {
    //do your magic here
    return !aBoolen; //example: negation
  }
});
```

or call it using a lambda expression, also with the example of negation:

```
ClickAndWaitForCondition(by, a->!a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You said: Takes a boolean and returns a boolean. But it's not what you're doing in your code. The `Function<Boolean, Boolean>` type means that you can invoke the following:

```
if (condition.apply(true) == false) break;
```

I don't quite know what you used to paste your snippet, but it capitalized everything, so as written it's not valid java, but surely that's not what's confusing you? Just in case: **all** keywords in java are entirely lowercase. `break;`, `if`, `for`, `public`, and `void`, and java is case sensitive for all of these.

Other than the part where the `apply` method needs a boolean parameter, and the capitalization, your code is fine.

If you're a little confused and you're actually looking for a thing that 'takes no parameters, and returns a boolean', i.e. what you're doing in the snippet, that does exist; it's `java.util.function.Supplier<Boolean>`.

Putting it all together and applying java conventions:

```
public void clickAndWaitForCondition(By locator, Supplier<Boolean> condition) {
  Webdriver.findElement(locator).click();
  for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    if (condition.get()) { // ' == true' is a tautology. Don't write it.
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click and wait for condition you can apply the waiting mechanism that is provided by Selenium. Like this:

```java
abstract class ClickAndWait implements Function<SearchContext, Boolean> {
    By by;
    public ClickAndWait(By by){
        this.by = by;
    }
    abstract boolean checkCondition(SearchContext context);
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(SearchContext context) {
        context.findElement(by).click();
        return checkCondition(context);
    }
}
```

And then do this:

```java
@Test
public void testClickAndWait(){
    Wait<SearchContext> waiter = new FluentWait<>(driver);
    waiter.until(new ClickAndWait(By.xpath("//PATH_TO_YOUR_ELEMENT")){
        @Override
        boolean checkCondition(SearchContext context) {
            // Evaluate conditions here;
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

You can check more examples with [waiting for conditions in Selenium](https://www.webelement.click/en/selenium_webdriver_java_custom_conditions_with_fluentwait).